# javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

i am new to html and trying to get the output of the following prog but unable to get the output dont no whats wrong pls help...

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="pink">
    <script src="valid.js" type="text/javascript" >

    </script>
        <form id="frm">
<center>
    <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <td  align="center" style="vertical-align:middle"><font size="6">Login<font> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td  align="center" style="vertical-align:middle"><font size="4">User id <font></td><td>       :<input type="text" id="User"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  align="center" style="vertical-align:middle"><font size="4">Password<font></td><td>:<input type="password" id="pass"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="Submit" value="Submit" object.onclick=valid()></td>

        </tr>
```

and the script is
 
          function valid()
          {
           
var x=document[frm][user].value;
           
var y=document[frm][pass].value;
            
if(x===null||x==="")
            
{
            
alert("Enter the user id and password");
            
return false;
           
}
           
else
             
if(x==="user"||y==="password")
                
 {
                     
alert("User id and password is correct");
                     
return true;
                 
}
                 
else
                     
alert("Wrong password or user id");
              
}
pls help i am trying to execute above prog but the javascript is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a syntax error, due to a wrong closing block.

That is, the `}` token at line 15 is wrong (you have to remove it).

To avoid this kind of erros, it is helpful being strict on code indentation, which aditionally improves code readability. This way, your fixed and formatted code would look similar to this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var fib1=0,fib2=1,fib=0;
        var num = prompt("Enter the number");
        if(num!=null && num>0)
        {
            document.write("<h1>" +num+ "fib are <br/></h1>");
            if(num == 1)
                document.write("<h1>" +fib1+ "</h1>");
            else
                document.write("<h1>" +fib1+ " " +fib2+ "</h1>");
            for(i=3;i<=num;i++)
            {
                fib=fib1+fib2;
                document.write("<h1>" +fib+ "</h1>");
                fib1=fib2;
                fib2=fib;
            }
        }
        else
            alert("no proper input");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mus use proper indentation to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: thanks bro..... it worked 
can u tell me which is the best application to use for web page development.

Comment: If it has solved the error, please, consider accepting the answer. On your question about a development tool, I usually use Eclipse for Java Webapps, VisualStudio if .NET webapps, and Notepad++ the rest of the times.

Comment: thanks but still when i retype the above code i am not getting the output
i have edited the above code

Comment: can u pleas check and tell me

Comment: You have an error at line 13 `document.write("<h1>" +fib1+ " " +fib2 " </h1>");` lack of a `+` sign after `fib2`

Comment: seriously ur good bro,i was like seeing that prog again and again and i was unable to find the error